# Problem with plotting complex valued function from (D,D) to D

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I'm having problem in plotting a complex valued function $D \times D$ to $D$.  Defined by
$$
f(z_1, z_2) = \max(z_1, z_2) = 
$$
if $|z_1| > |z_2|$
$$
\max(z_1, z_2) = z_1  
$$
else
if $|z_1| < |z_2|$
$$
\max(z_1, z_2) = z_2  
$$
else if $|z_1| = |z_2| $ and $\arg(z_1) > \arg(z_2)$
$$
\max(z_1, z_2) = z_1
$$
else
$$  
\max(z_1, z_2) = z_2
$$
.$D = \{z\in C :  |z| <= 1\}$ i.e. closed unit disk centered at the origin of the complex plane. I know several plotting or visualization techniques $C \longrightarrow C$, But could not find out any such $C \times C \longrightarrow C$. If every details of the mapping cannot be covered to a single image i.e. total visualization is done by multiple images, still it is okay for me.

Comment: Maximum of two complex numbers does not make sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm you are correct as there is no partial ordering. But still in generic way, is there any plotting technique to visualize map (D,D) to D?